# FCM and other API signing before APK uploading

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I have created an app. and I have signed its release version. I this app I have used Google API's such as Google maps and FCM.

I have read documentation and observed how to generate release certificates for googles, for FCM how to generate the Json file.

But another thing came into my mind and I am not sure if that is right or wrong. Because I could not find any direct answer of it.

**Question:**

> I have made JSON file of fcm by login  using different gmail id. And I
>   have my official google play account on another gmail id. Now my question is can we use 2 different gmail ids for both or I need to generate JSON file using same gmail id which is used to make a google play account.

Please discuss over it

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can use 2 different IDs also.

Comment: @AmitabhSarkar please be more clear

Comment: you can use one gmail account to use fcm and another gmail account for google play store.